# Reimplementing Alias method in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, reinventing-the-wheel, c++17

In the following I reimplement the Walker-Vose Alias method for sampling from nonuniform, discrete probability distributions.
I am well aware that there is https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution
which I would use for production code.

- `alias_lib.h` contains the main logic.
- `main.cpp` contains example usage.
- `CMakeLists.txt` contains a minimal cmake file.

`alias_lib.h`

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

typedef double real;


template <typename T>
T pop(std::vector<T>& V)
// Remove and return the last element of a vector.
{
    auto val = V.back();
    V.pop_back();
    return val;
}


template <typename RNE>
auto get_r(RNE& gen)
// Return a real number from [0, 1) using a Random Number Engine
{
    static std::uniform_real_distribution<real> dist(0.0, 1.0);
    return dist(gen);
};



class AliasSampler
// This class implements the Walker-Vose Alias Sampling method.
//
// The initializing weights do not have to be normalized.
// The algorithm is described
// [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20131029203736/http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~vose/Publications/random.pdf)
// The naming of variables follows the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_method) (As of 2022-10-31).
{
    public:
        AliasSampler() = delete;

        AliasSampler(const std::vector<real>& weights)
            : K_(weights.size())
        {
            // [...] If Ui = 1, the corresponding value Ki will never be consulted and is unimportant,
            //      but a value of Ki = i is sensible. [...]

            std::iota(K_.begin(), K_.end(), 0);

            p_.reserve(weights.size());
            std::transform(
                weights.begin(), weights.end(),
                std::back_inserter(p_),
                [result = std::reduce(weights.begin(), weights.end())]
                    (real w) -> real
                    {
                        return w / result;
                    }
            );

            U_.reserve(weights.size());
            std::transform(
                p_.begin(), p_.end(),
                std::back_inserter(U_),
                [&, this]
                    (real x) -> real
                    {
                        return p_.size() * x;
                    }
            );

            // [...] As the lookup procedure is slightly faster if y < Ui (because Ki does not need to be consulted),
            //      one goal during table generation is to maximize the sum of the Ui.
            //      Doing this optimally turns out to be NP hard,  but a greedy algorithm comes reasonably close: rob from the richest and give to the poorest.
            //      That is, at each step choose the largest Ui and the smallest Uj.
            //      Because this requires sorting the Ui, it requires O(n log n) time. [...] (See the Wikipedia article)
            // For this reason we partition into small and large indices and use them in a sorted fashion.

            std::vector<std::size_t> indices_(U_.size());
            std::iota(indices_.begin(), indices_.end(), 0);
            std::sort(indices_.begin(), indices_.end(),
                   [&, this]
                        (int a, int b) -> bool
                        {
                            return U_[a] < U_[b];
                        });

            // I could use std::partition for partitioning into smaller and larger, **but**
            // AFAIK this would not make use of the fact that the array is already sorted.
            std::vector<std::size_t> smaller, larger;

            for (std::size_t i = 0; U_[indices_[i]] < 1; ++i) {
                smaller.push_back(indices_[i]);
            };

            for (std::size_t i = U_.size() - 1; U_[indices_[i]] >= 1; --i) {
                larger.push_back(indices_[i]);
            };

            while (smaller.size() && larger.size()) {
                std::size_t s = pop(smaller);
                std::size_t l = pop(larger);
                K_[s] = l;
                U_[l] = U_[l] - (1. - U_[s]);
                if (U_[l] < 1) {
                    smaller.push_back(l);
                } else {
                    larger.push_back(l);
                };
            };

            // [...] If one category empties before the other, the remaining entries may
            //      have U_i set to 1 with negligible error. [...] (See the Wikipedia article)
            while (smaller.size()) {
                std::size_t s = pop(smaller);
                U_[s] = 1.;
            };

            while (larger.size()) {
                std::size_t l = pop(larger);
                U_[l] = 1.;
            };
        };

        const auto& probabilities() const
        {
            return p_;
        };


        template <typename RNE>
        auto operator()(RNE& gen) const
        // Return a random number according to the given probabilities
        // at initialization using a Random Number Engine.
        {
            auto x = get_r(gen);
            auto i = static_cast<size_t>(p_.size() * x);
            auto y = p_.size() * x - i;

            return y < U_[i] ? i : K_[i];
        };

        auto min() const
        {
            return 0;
        };

        auto max() const
        {
            return p_.size() - 1;
        };

    private:
        std::vector<real> p_{};
        std::vector<std::size_t> K_{};
        std::vector<real> U_{};
        std::vector<std::size_t> indices_{};
};
```

`main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <map>
#include <iomanip>

#include "alias_lib.h"

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());

    AliasSampler sampler({1., 2., 3., 1.5, 1., 1.5});

    std::map<int, int> map;
    for(int n=0; n<100000; ++n) {
        ++map[sampler(gen)];
    }
    for(const auto& [num, count] : map) {
        std::cout << num << " generated " << std::setw(4) << count << " times\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(test_alias_sampling)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

add_library(alias_lib
    INTERFACE
        alias_lib.h
)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_compile_options(main PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra -Werror)
target_link_libraries(main alias_lib)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Make it satify the RandomNumberDistribution requirement

Your sampler class basically implements a specific random number distribution. The [random number distributions in the standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random#Random_number_distributions) all satisfy the [RandomNumberDistribtion requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomNumberDistribution). It seems your class already satisfies many of the requirements, but it's missing some features, like the `result_type` and `param_type` type aliases, `param()`, `reset()`, an `operator()` that also takes a set of weights, comparison operators and `std::ostream` and `std::istream` operator overloads.

By conforming exactly to this requirement, your class will be a true drop-in replacement for existing standard random number distributions.

## Avoid out-of-class utility functions and type aliases

You defined `real`, `pop()`, `get_r()` outside `class AliasSampler`. This means these names will now live in the global namespace, and can potentially conflict with other code that wants to define those things. You can make `pop()` and `get_r()` `private` member functions, and you can even move the definition of `real` into the class.

## Use of STL algorithms

STL algorithms are very helpful tools, but sometimes they are very unwieldy. You have examples of both cases in your code: using `std::reduce()` to sum a vector is very concise, but then `std::transform()` to fill a vector is looking like a monstrosity. Sometimes a good old `for`-loop is simpler and better than an algorithm. Consider:

```
p_.reserve(weights.size());
auto sum_weights = std::reduce(weights.begin(), weights.end());
for (auto weight: weights) {
    p_.push_back(weight / sum_weights);
}
```

With [C++20's ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) it might become a bit nicer to use algorithms:

```
p_.reserve(weights.size());
auto sum_weights = std::reduce(weights.begin(), weights.end());
std::ranges::copy(std::views::transform(weights, [&](auto weight){
    return weight / sum_weights;
}, std::back_inserter(p_));
```

Or with [C++23](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/to):

```
auto sum_weights = std::reduce(weights.begin(), weights.end());
p_ = std::ranges::transform(weights, [&](auto weight){
    return weight / sum_weights;
}) | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();
```

## Avoid unnecessary use of floating point

The Wikipedia article mentions that the algorithm requires you to generate a random number between 0 and 1. However, the only reason to do so is to select a random index into `p_`. Instead of literally doing what the article mentions and using a `std::uniform_real_distribution<real>` to generate that random number, consider using a `std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t>(0, p_.size() - 1)`. This avoids the multiplication and `static_cast` back to `size_t`.

## Don't store temporary data in member variables

The vector `indices_` is only used in the constructor to build the tables. It should not be a member variable, but just be declared inside the constructor.

From the Wikipedia article it looks like you only need \$U_i\$ and \$K_i\$ to sample the distribution, \$p_i\$ is only mentiond in the table generation section. I'm not sure why you are using it in `operator()`?

## Stray semicolon

There is an unnecessary semicolon after the definition of `operator()`. Make sure you turn on compiler warnings, and fix all the warnings the compiler reports.

## Documentation

It's really good to see that you have linked to a paper and the Wikipedia article describing the algorithm, and mentioning that your are matching the naming conventions from one of those.

You could also consider using the [Doxygen](https://doxygen.nl/) format to document your code; this also allows the Doxygen tools to produce cross-references HTML and PDF output of the documentation you wrote.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great and on-point review.

Comment: After incorporating nearly all your comments I think that the raised point of "Avoid unnecessary use of floating point" is actually wrong in that particular case. (Although I wholeheartedly agreed with you at first glance.)
If it would be only about obtaining a random index to access `U_[i]` or `K_[i]` it would be true, but we also need the comparison of `y < U_[i]` where `y` cannot be an integer number on a conceptional level. One could argue that it still would be better to obtain the random number from [0, n) instead of [0, 1), but IMHO it has to be real.

Comment: this is a placeholder comment to inform you about the above one. Somehow I could not use the `@` notation there.

Comment: If it's necessary then of course by all means use it. It's also not a hard rule, which is why I used the term "avoid" instead of saying "never use". Often if you can use integers instead of floating point it is better, since you don't have to worry about rounding issues and potential loss of precision when converting float point numbers to/from integers.